# FCM - Sending android push notifications by device tokens and environment/group

Tags: android, push-notification, environment

I would like to implement a method in which android push notifications through FCM are sent by **both** specific device tokens and an environment/group.

Just like there are two environments which needed to be implemented for sending iOS push notifications through APNS (sandbox & production), I would like to do the same using FCM.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For setup FCM push notification just goto [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) then add project and setup other settings for environments. Then goto cloud messaging tab and you will fine "server key" and "sender id". You need to share this with server side developer. From server side need to handle push notification for specific device tokens and an environment/group.